# Shift some items of enumerate

Tags: beamer, enumerate

I have `enumerate` in a slide, I would like the beginning, including the bullet, of the 2nd and the 3rd `\item` shift a little bit on the right, compared to the 1st `\item`:

```
Item1
  Item2
  Item3
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a possible solution using nested `enumerate` environments and a redefinition of the `enumerate subitem` template to use the counter for the first level:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{enumerate}
\item First item.
  \setbeamertemplate{enumerate subitem}{\insertsubenumlabel.\stepcounter{enumi}}
  \begin{enumerate} 
  \stepcounter{enumii}
  \item Second item.
  \item Third item.
  \end{enumerate}
\item Fourth item.
\end{enumerate}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For the case of items with balls:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{enumerate}
\item First item.
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate subitem}
{
  \begin{pgfpicture}{-1ex}{-0.55ex}{1ex}{1ex}
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{subitem projected}
    {\pgftransformscale{1.75}\pgftext{\normalsize\pgfuseshading{bigsphere}}}
    \pgftext{%
      \usebeamerfont*{subitem projected}%
      \insertsubenumlabel\stepcounter{enumi}}
  \end{pgfpicture}%
}
  \begin{enumerate} 
  \stepcounter{enumii}
  \item Second item.
  \item Third item.
  \end{enumerate}
\item Fourth item.
\end{enumerate}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This does not work when you use `ball` enumerations, the subitems are plain text, not balls. I tried looking through the beamer sources for the definition  of the `ball` style, but no luck so far :(

Comment: @TomBombadil I updated my answer with this possibility; you find the definitions of the styles in `beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty`.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I was sitting the last minutes thinking what the name of that neat tool for finding strings in all files in a directory was: `grep`, of cause ;)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should work with any style, but it does move only the first line of the item:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{enumerate}
\item First item.
\addtolength{\itemindent}{1cm} % move right
\item Second item.
\item Third item.
\addtolength{\itemindent}{-1cm} % move left
\item Fourth item.
\end{enumerate}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```